# Using HTML5, in Orchard CMS mobile application

Tags: html, mobile, content-management-system, orchardcms

I was just reading the guidelines and trying to get my head around the apparent contradiction in http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/UI-guidelines-for-theme-authors.ashx

On one hand, it says:
"Orchard assumes the use of HTML5... it is a strong recommendation. "

On the other hand it also says:
"Your web pages should work even if JavaScript is disabled in the browser"

How can the HTML5 tags possible work w/o JavaScript - which they have recommended as a solution? Since I'm doing a mobile application, should I totally ignore HTML5 tags then as the safest approach for browser compatibility in mobile?

**Update:** Anyone had a look at Twitter's new mobile site in HTML5? Is it using HTML5 tags and just focusing on modern smart phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a different wrapper for the widgets that does have to depend on the generic wrapper for widgets which has pre-configured HTML5 tags like `<header />`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to be a little more specific about the problems you are anticipating, in particular as compared to the same thing done *without* HTML 5. It's not clear to me whether this is a comment about Orchard or about HTML 5.
Another thing to keep in mind is that while we recommend HTML 5, you can perfectly well replace all the markup into whatever dialect you prefer to use.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about HTML5 tags. <header><footer><section><article> etc. What Orchard mentions with regards to HTML5 is also the tags (to begin with), since it includes the HTML5 shiv

Comment: Well, without JavaScript, and on browsers that don't support HTML 5, you may lose some styling, yes. But for those browsers you'll need some form of downlevel theme, won't you?
Is there a specific problem that you can't work around that you need help with?

Comment: As you probably also know, browser that don't support HTML5 tags don't just 'lose some styling', the HTML5 tags literally collapse/close prematurely, which is much more serious than a pretty/not-so-pretty scenario. End-solution to be posted.

Comment: Again, you are making a comment about HTML 5, not specifically about Orchard, and in Orchard you can replace all the markup and render in any HTML dialect you want.

Comment: Since according to the Orchard documentation's suggestion: "Your web pages should work even if JavaScript is disabled in the browser"... 
doesn't it occur to you that end-users (who read and take the documentation seriously) might take a piss at needing to overcome/overwrite the default widget wrapper (which rely on JavaScript to render the HTML5 contained within)? I suggest removing that kind of statement from the documentation unless the default Orchard setup actually goes in line with the 'preaching'.

Comment: If you or someone else finds specific problems and files bugs for them, we will handle them.